# How would I need to change my code to fit into the HKEY_USERS format instead of HKCU?

Tags: powershell

```
We are upgrading our Software to its 2019 version. Apparently it is a 
bugger, so it has been suggested to do a clean install including deleting 
some registry keys from previous versions.

We also want to save the autologins of our users so they don't need to 
reset them up and we can also do something similar with new deployments.

I got some code working for what we want to do, but the problem is that 
when I went to add it to our uninstall script, the uninstall script has 
some different paths using HKEY_USERS vs my HKCU.
```

How can I modify my code to fit into our uninstall script which is using 
HKEY_USERS?

Haven't tried anything other than the original code yet. Not sure where 
to begin. This is my 1st attempt using powershell (or any coding really).

```
    #Basically this is supposed to grab the users autologin key, save it, 
    #then after nuking the reg, put it back

    $path = 'HKCU:\Software\SolidWorks\Applications\PDMWorks 
    Enterprise\ServerConfig\FakeVaultName'
    $autologinkey = "HKCU\Software\SolidWorks\Applications\PDMWorks 
    Enterprise\ServerConfig\FakeVaultName"
    $user=(Get-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name User).user.ToLower()

    #/y forces overwriting the existing file without prompt.

    if($user -ne 'fakeusername' -and $user){
    reg export $autologinkey "$env:TEMP\fakekeyname.reg" /y
    }


    #These next steps need to be done after the uninstall/reg scrubbing

    if($user -ne 'fakeusername' -and $user){
    reg.exe import "$env:TEMP\fakekeyname.reg"
    }

    #I think this could maybe get away with just the else part instead of 
    #elseif + the user?

    elseif($user -eq 'fakeusername' -or !$user){
    reg.exe import 
    "\\fakecompanyname.com\Files\Public\IT\Protected\Projects\SOLIDWORKS 
    2019 
    deployment\Vault fakeusername auto login keys.reg"
    }

    #I need to make my code work with the following that loops through 
    #all the different users on the machine (not the whole code, just the 
    #HKEY_USERS part that I'm concerned with

    # This is where you can read/modify a users portion of the registry

    $unwantedDirectories += "registry::HKEY_USERS\ 
    {0}\Software\SolidWorks" -f 
    $($Item.SID)
    $unwantedDirectories += "registry::HKEY_USERS\{0}\Software\SRAC" -f 
    $($Item.SID)
    $unwantedDirectories += "registry::HKEY_USERS\{0}\Software\eDrawings" 
    -f 
    $($Item.SID)
    $unwantedDirectories += "registry::HKEY_USERS\{0}\Software\SOLIDWORKS 
    2017" -f $($Item.SID)
```

I don't know where to begin. My code works, but not sure how to tie it in 
with the other HKEY_USERS part.

Please advise.

Edit: 7/9/2019
The script is kind of working, but it will import the reg key to the logged in user vs. the profile we want it to. Below is current working (mostly) code.

```bsh
###############################################################################
#This part is ran before the reg nuke.

$autologinpath = registry::HKEY_USERS\0}\Software\SolidWorks\Applications\PDMWorks Enterprise\ServerConfig\FakeVaultName' -f $($Item)
$autologinkey = "HKU\{0}\Software\SolidWorks\Applications\PDMWorks Enterprise\ServerConfig\FakeVaultName" -f $($Item)
$autologinuser=(Get-ItemProperty -Path $autologinpath -Name User).user.ToLower()

if($autologinuser -ne 'fakeusername' -and $autologinuser){
reg export $autologinkey "$env:TEMP\fakekeyname.reg" /y
}

###############################################################################
#This part is ran after the reg nuke.

if($user -ne 'fakeusername' -and $autologinuser){
   reg.exe import "$env:TEMP\fakekeyname.reg"
}

else {
   reg.exe import "\\fakecompanyname.com\Files\Public\IT\Protected\Projects\SOLIDWORKS 2019 deployment\Vault fakeusername auto login keys.reg"
}
```

Edit: 7/9/2019 2:09pm

Thanks for the help! I think we got it. We ended up doing a manual add of the reg key values. Probably not very elegant, but seems to be working.

```bsh
Else {
    reg add $autologinkey /v "SettingsFromServer" /t REG_DWORD /f /d #
    reg add $autologinkey /v "User" /t REG_SZ /f /d fakeusername
    reg add $autologinkey /v "Config" /t REG_BINARY /f /d blahblahblahinfinity..
    reg add $autologinkey /v "CacheW" /t REG_DWORD /f /d #
    reg add $autologinkey /v "SinglePointLogin" /t REG_DWORD /f /d #
    }
```

Comment: PowerShell allows wildcards in path segments, so you can iterate over `registry::HKEY_USERS\*\Software` if you want to get the keys for all users indiscriminately.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, that got me started. The 1st few lines of code are working, but I'm now having issues with exporting the key to a reg file part of the code. $path=registry::HKEY_USERS\*\Software\SolidWorks\Applications\PDMWorks Enterprise\ServerConfig\FakeVaultName'
$autologinkey = "registry::HKU\Software\SolidWorks\Applications\PDMWorks Enterprise\ServerConfig\FakeVaultName"
$user=(Get-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name User).user.ToLower()

if($user -ne 'fakeusername' -and $user){
   reg export $autologinkey "$env:TEMP\autologinkey.reg" /y
}

Comment: You can always [edit] your question; this is much more convenient than trying to stuff code in comments. (Also, make sure to clearly mention what you're doing and what's not working; "having issues" is hard to troubleshoot for people who can't have a look at your screen.)